# Vertex Color not showing up in Cycles Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

very strange problem:

A SpeedTree model comes with vertex colors for shading control.
These vertex colors show up in Shaded Mode / EEVEE Render, but disappear when switching to Cycles. They are neither rendered in color, nor are they being used in my shader which I made for color variation.

This is a consistent problem with 2.83 and 2.90.1.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also attached the file below, maybe something is off there?

https://filehorst.de/d/dlymjper

Answer (score 3):

Update: This is due to the naming of the vertex color set. Naming it something else than "color" fixes the issue.